# ul is not inside div container

Tags: html, css

Why my container is not background color red and ul is not inside div container ??

**STYLE:**

```
#container {
            width:1000px
            }

#categoryorder {
            float:left;
            width:500px;
            margin:0 0 0 50px;
            display:inline;
            list-style-type:none
}

#categoryorder li {
            color:#003366;
            font-size:20px;
            float:left;
            width:196px;
            background-color:#fcfcfc;
            border: 2px solid #dddddd;
            margin:0 50px 50px 0;
            line-height:50px;
            text-align:center;
            display:inline;
            cursor:move
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="background-color: red;">
     <ul id="categoryorder">
         <li id="ID_1">1</li>
         <li id="ID_2">2</li>
         <li id="ID_3">3</li>
         <li id="ID_4">4</li>
         <li id="ID_5">5</li>
         <li id="ID_6">6</li>
         <li id="ID_7">7</li>
         <li id="ID_8">8</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vrVAP/84/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are floating all of the elements within, without clearing them. Create a clear class and then add an element at the bottom:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="background-color: red;">
     <ul id="categoryorder">
         <li id="ID_1">1</li>
         <li id="ID_2">2</li>
         <li id="ID_3">3</li>
         <li id="ID_4">4</li>
         <li id="ID_5">5</li>
         <li id="ID_6">6</li>
         <li id="ID_7">7</li>
         <li id="ID_8">8</li>
     </ul>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clr{
    clear:both;
    font-size:0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/89VXh/)

Comment: This is the correct answer - however you should use the clearfix techniques as defined in this article http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ as adding empty `div` elements just for the sake of clearing floats is a bad practice.

Comment: @ninty9notout - Why is it the correct answer? An extra div is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @j08691 that was how you used to do clearfix in the good old days, before pseudo elements, therefore it's a valid answer. I've also mentioned that it is a bad practice, which takes care of the unnecessary argument, and given a link to a resource that provides ways clearfix is achieved in modern browsers.

Comment: @ninty9notout - valid sure, I won't dispute that, but as you point out it was an old way of doing things that requires extra, non-semantic markup.

Answer (score 6):

When you float the children you essentially remove them from the flow of the document and the container element's height shrinks to nothing. Add `overflow:auto;` to your `#container` div to restore the behavior you seek.

```
#container {
    width:1000px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9tu37/)**

Note that this answer doesn't require any extra (non-semantic) divs to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

You are floating your elements and need to add `overflow: hidden` to your PARENT container to restore the height. Use this and you wont need to add an extra div to your flow.

```
#container {
            width:1000px; overflow: hidden;
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saUp7/1/

Comment: Finally I understood why my floated content made the containing DIV shrink... :-) But what is the difference between using overflow: hidden or auto? It also works with auto as per @j08691 answer.

Comment: in this case they both act similar and just clear the floats, overflow hidden will hide extra content but only if there is a set height fixed

Answer (score 1):

Change your `float:left` to `display:inline-block;`

Css:

```
#categoryorder {
     width:500px;
     margin:0 0 0 50px;
     display:inline-block;    /*from float:left; to display:inline-block; */
     list-style-type:none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zUMd/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use display:inline-block instead (and add vertical-align: top for better look).

Float is designed for cutting block from flow, so it is normal behaviour for that: you have no no-floated blocks inside, so flow is near nothing.

Inline-blocks are in flow, so it will work.

And just one trick for inline-blocks: remember the spaces! If they are in source, there will be small margins within blocks, so just comment your indents

> something
>
> another
>
> (look up to source)